# I have career gap after bachelors degree and irrelevant work experience. How do I write SOP for MS admission in US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I pursued a Bachelor of Technology in Electronics and Communication Engineering stream and I completed the course in 2010. I was jobless for more than a year so I did a 3 months course in Java. Im Sun certified. I still wasn't able to find a job. I got a job in a Business Process Outsourcing company as a customer support associate. I had to take the job, as I didn't have any choice. I worked from Aug 2012 to Nov 2013. Now I'm interested in doing an MS. I'm afraid I don't get admitted. I'm especially interested in University of Texas at Austin. I don't know how to project my negative points in the SOP. I don't know what points to include and what to not. I have no clue. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike employers in industry, I believe that graduate admissions committees don't care if there are gaps, irrelevant work experience, or changes of direction in your employment.  Their sole concern are your credentials and capabilities to do academic work.  You should focus all your attention on communicating your skills and capabilities to do Masters-level Computer Science work.  This includes your course grades as an undergrad, your GRE scores, your computer experience in industry, your recommendation letters, and your engagement with professional and academic communities.

(Business schools are probably an exception to this.  Work history is probably important to getting accepted in an MBA program.)